# Visualforce inputField

Tags: apex

[image]

The fields newAppointment.Appointment_Data__c and newAppointment.Duration_in_minutes__c are required, the button with action = "{! CreatDoctor}" will enter another page, but I cannot go to it because the fields are required. Please tell me how to change it

Поля newAppointment.Appointment_Data__c и newAppointment.Duration_in_minutes__c являются обязательными, кнопка с action="{!creatDoctor}" введет на другую страницу, однако перейти на нее, я не могу тк поля обязательные. Подскажите пожалуйста как это изменить

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<apex:actionRegion>` to enclose the button with `action = "{! CreatDoctor}"`.

```
<apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:commandButton value="Add a new doctor" action = "{! CreatDoctor}"/>
</apex:actionRegion>
```